# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

So, I have these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inart_ps_categories` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inart_ps_category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_children` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inart_ps_category_associations` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inart_ps_category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (categoryid) REFERENCES `categories` (categoryid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (inart_ps_category_id) REFERENCES `inart_ps_categories` (inart_ps_category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

It outputs "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" for no reason. The first Foreign key is correct and if I erase the second one, the query is executed. Can you see something wrong here?

Comment: I adapted @Lennart's [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb85e45bab7c91f56f98340e9c072520). Thought that a `UNIQUE` constraint on a `NOT NULL` field would work correctly, as a `FOREIGN KEY`! WTF! That's one **`MASSIVE`** bug - c.f. [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7f00737d694963cb8f3bd438c206b155) and [Firebird](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=273e45e74ae1e9d331ae2ada51ccb6e1) - both solid RDBMS's! HTH!

Comment: @Vérace, for your amusement it actually works but only if you explicitly declare the constraint as in: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3d6021b28f50e7732df8c345991f42b It seems to work as expected in Maria 10.5 but not before, so there may be hope. Perhaps that is why PHP and MySQL are often seen together, unexpected behaviour is already part of of the daily experience ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your categories table, your only problem is that the referenced columns like `inart_ps_category_id` need an index, which you can achieve by using `KEY(inart_ps_category_id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inart_ps_categories` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inart_ps_category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_children` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY(`inart_ps_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inart_ps_category_associations` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inart_ps_category_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (categoryid) REFERENCES `categories` (categoryid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (inart_ps_category_id) REFERENCES `inart_ps_categories` (inart_ps_category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: What are the semantics of a foreign key against something that's not a real key (as in p.k. or unique )? I was a bit surprised when I saw your answer so I created a fiddle: 
 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b3aae8fc4b48a8f0736c811e4855bdc   The foreign key seems to have no effect at all, is it some kind of informational constraint?

Comment: @Lennart - check out my comment to the OP's question - I hope you haven't been bombarded with notifications - same apology goes to nbk!

Comment: @Lennart: your FK from child to parent isn't working because MySQL silently ignores inline foreign keys (as part of the column definitions) without telling you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes I realized it and made a comment above. Fixing that reveals that the delete cascades despite that there still are parents that satisfy the constraint:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e3924713a8e4943ee63f030f335651e

Answer (score 0):

A Foreign Key should only reference the **Primary Key** of another table.

The one causing you difficulties *does not*.

```
CREATE TABLE inart_ps_categories 
( id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, inart_ps_category_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
. . . 
, PRIMARY KEY ( id )                                           <-- Primary Key 
)

CREATE TABLE inart_ps_category_associations 
( id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, inart_ps_category_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
. . . 
, PRIMARY KEY ( id )
. . . 
  FOREIGN KEY ( inart_ps_category_id ) 
    REFERENCES inart_ps_categories ( inart_ps_category_id )    <-- NOT Primary Key 
)
```

Comment: Check out my comments to @Lennart!